# Sum of squares of combinations

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I am solving a PhD entrance paper at home.The problem is as follows: let $C_r=^nC_r$.Then what is the value of $C_0^2+3C_1^2+\dots+(2n+1)C_n^2$.

I have evaluated the value for $C_0^2+C_1^2+\dots+C_n^2$ which is happened to be $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$.

Comment: I am sorry for that typing error.What I tried to mean was (2n!/n!n!)

Comment: (1) You can edit your question. (2) Please do not have LaTeX-only titles, since then they can't be right-clicked like normal hyperlinks.

Comment: @runway44: +1 And I thought I was the only one who doesn't like that.

Comment: [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A037965) says it is $n\binom{2(n-1)}{n-1}$.

Comment: Hint: write this as $2\sum kC_k\times C_{n-k}+ \sum C_k^2$. You know the second sum. For the first, replace $kC_k$ with $n\times \,{}^{n-1}C_{k-1}$, then use Vandermonde’s identity.

Comment: Thank You@Mike Earnest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_k(2k+1)\binom{n}{k}^2
&=\sum_k\binom{n}{k}^2+2\sum_kk\binom{n}{k}^2\tag1\\
&=\binom{2n}{n}+2n\sum_k\binom{n-1}{k-1}\binom{n}{n-k}\tag2\\
&=\binom{2n}{n}+2n\binom{2n-1}{n-1}\tag3\\[3pt]
&=(n+1)\binom{2n}{n}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: distribute the $2k+1$
$(2)$: $k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ and $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$ and [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)
$(3)$: Vandermonde's Identity
$(4)$: $2\binom{2n-1}{n-1}=\binom{2n}{n}$

Answer (score 2):

Generating functions:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n (2k+1)\binom{n}{k}^2=[x^0]\left(\sum_{k=0}^n (2k+1)\binom{n}{k}x^k\right)\left(\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} x^{-r} \right) $$

Note $[x^s]f(x)$ extracts the $x^s$ coefficient of a function $f(x)$.

The second sum you can evaluate to $(1+x^{-1})^n$, and the first is

$$ 2x\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}kx^{k-1}\right)+\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k = 2x\left[\frac{d}{dx}(1+x)^n\right]+(1+x)^n. $$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Yes thank you.But I want to know about the generating function you have used.Can you please tell me where can I read about it?And are there any other method without using the generating function.

Comment: @user481975 The generating function I have used is simply the binomial theorem for $(1+u)^n$. A version of this proof that does not mention generating functions is sketched by Mike Earnest's comment and robjohn's answer.

Comment: I am very sorry if I am asking stupid question.But I don't quite follow how does the generating function follows from bionomial theorem.

Comment: @user481975 Which function in my answer are you talking about? Are you talking about the first equation as a whole, or just $\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r} x^{-r}=(1+x^{-1})^n$ to begin with, or ...? If you're not familiar with generating functions, you can accept robjohn's answer and read up on them later.

Comment: I am talking about $\sum_{0}^{n}(2k+1)^{n}C_{k}^2=[x^0] (\sum_{0}^{n}(2k+1)^{n}C_{k}x^k)(\sum_{0}^{n}C_{r}x^-r$

Comment: It's not that I am not familiar with generating function but unfortunately I have not seen this generating function before.Therefore I am curious to learn this.I hope this is not too much trouble for you.

Comment: Consider two generating functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. When multiplying out $$ f(x)g(x^{-1})=\left(\sum_k f_k x^k\right)\left(\sum_r g_r x^{-r}\right),$$ the terms will look like $f_kg_rx^{k-r}$. The constant term will be this summed over all $k$ and $r$ in which $k=r$ (so that $x^{k-r}$ is $1$), in other words the $x^0$ coefficient will be $\sum f_k g_k$. This is precisely the trick for using generating functions to simplify $\sum_k \binom{2k}{k}^2$, just now I am applying it instead with coefficients $f_k=(2k+1)\binom{n}{k}$ and $g_r=\binom{n}{r}$.

Comment: Thank you I got it!!☺️ Appreciate your help.